# ¿Cómo aplicar estilos a un mensaje de error en php?

Tags: php, html, css, formularios

Este es mi loginusuario.php me gustaría darle estilo a los errores, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['conexion']))
    {
        $error = "";

        if (empty($_POST['DNI']) && empty($_POST['contrasenia']))
        {   

          $error.="Error en DNI y Contraseña"; 
        }             
        else
        {
           if (empty($_POST['DNI']))
              {
                 $error.="Error en DNI";

              }
           else 
              {
                 $DNI = $_POST['DNI'];
              }
          if (empty($_POST['contrasenia']))
             {
                 $error.="Error en Contraseña";

             }
          else 
             {
                $contrasenia = $_POST['contrasenia'];
             }
        }

        if(!empty($error))
           {

               header("location: loginusuario.php?err=$error");
               exit();


           } 
        else
            {

            $req = "SELECT count(*) FROM usuario where DNI = '$DNI' and 
                 contrasenia = '$contrasenia'";

            $result = mysqli_query($coneccion, $req);

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

               if($row[0] == 1)
                  {  
                   $_SESSION['DNI'] = $DNI; 
                      header("location: usuario.php?DNI=$DNI");
                     exit();
                  }
               else 
                  {
                     header("location: loginusuario.php?falso=DNI o contraseña "
                             . "son incorrectos");
                     exit();
                  }
            }
    }

?>

   <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['err']))
    {
       echo $_GET["err"];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['falso']))
    {
       echo $_GET["falso"];
    }

?>
```

Pregunta: ahora lo que me gustaría hacer es que mis mensajes de error , por ejemplo el de error en contraseña, Error en DNI y Contraseña ..... que están en la variable err dentro del header("location.... **darles estilo, que estén en el medio de la pantalla y que salgan por ejemplo en color rojo y negrita**

Answer (score 5):

Para hacer esto se recomienda usar clases CSS, de este modo el código es mucho más fácil de mantener, dado que si quieres cambiar algo sólo cambiar la clase CSS, no tienes que ir buscando en todos los HTML dónde das estilo a los elementos.

En cuanto a PHP, dado que en el código los errores se van concatenando, una forma simple de hacerlo sería trabajando con dos variables:

1. Una variable serviría para crear el contenedor de los mensajes de error. En este caso usaremos un `div`
2. Otra variable sería la que va recogiendo los posibles mensajes de error. Sería tu actual variable `$error`.

Luego, haces uso de [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php) para mostrar el contenido de `$error` dentro del contenedor.

Un ejemplo de aplicación:

## PHP

```
/*
    *Declaramos aquí el contenedor
    *Nótese el uso de %s que luego se cambiará 
    *por el valor que haya en $error, sea cual sea
*/
$cssError='<div class="error">%s</div>';

/*Declaramos la variable de concatenación*/
$error="";

/*Contenido que se agrega en cualquier parte del código*/
$error.="<p>error en DNI</p>";
/*Más código, cualquiera...*/

/*Más contenido que se agrega*/
$error.="<p>error en contraseña</p>";

/*Más código, cualquiera...*/

/*Más contenido que se agrega*/
$error.="<p>error en el nombre</p>";

/*
    *Finalmente imprimimos en lugar de %s 
    *lo que se haya recogido en $error
    *a lo largo del código
    *NÓTESE que usamos un if, para que 
    *en caso de no haber error no crear elementos vacíos
*/
if ($error) {
    echo sprintf($cssError, $error);
}
```

## CSS

Declaras una clase `.error` donde das formato al texto. En este ejemplo para simplificar pondremos el color de letra en rojo, lo pondremos más grande y en cursiva:

```
.error {
    font-color: red;
    font-size: medium;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

## Snippet

El código PHP anterior podría tener esta salida, ligada el .css, quedaría así:

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: medium;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="error">
  <p>error en DNI</p>
  <p>error en contraseña</p>
  <p>error en el nombre</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es tan sencillo como añadirle algunas etiquetas HTML con clases de estilo
en la salida de `echo`

Posibles respuestas

```
<?php
    //Respuesta #1
    if(isset($_GET['err']))
    {
       echo "<div class = 'myModalClass' >" . $_GET["err"] . "</div>";
    }

    //Respuesta #2
    if(isset($_GET['err']))
    {
       ?> <div class = "myModalClass" ><?=$_GET["err"]?> </div> <?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: El estilo lo debes definir tu, usando tu propia nocion, gustos y conocimientos HTML. Me ajuste en la respuesta a como darle estilo, no a que salga como quieres el estilo.

Comment: gracias, lo probare y te dire si me funciona, un saludo